# How can I mark an email as "Done" and read at once in Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I would like to mark a conversation as done and read at once.

Is this somehow possible in Inbox by Gmail?

[image: Screenshot of a conversation that is unread and not marked as done yet]

Comment: **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No but you can use keyboard shortcuts to move pretty quickly. <kbd>[</kbd> on an open email will mark as done and open the next email (obviously it will be read as it's been opened). <kbd>]</kbd> will do the same but open the previous email.

Make sure you have keyboard shortcuts turned on in settings.